# Convert the result of Throwable.getStackTrace() to a string that depicts the stacktrace

Tags: java, tostring

Easiest way to convert the **result** of `Throwable.getStackTrace()` to a *string* that depicts the stacktrace?

Comment: Add codes and be clear what you have worked on ...also see my edit...

Comment: @gokulprasad Please review the answers given below.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to start with getStackTrace, then it's easier to use printStackTrace than getStackTrace if all you want is the string representation.

```
String trace;
try(StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw)) {
  t.printStackTrace(pw);
  pw.flush();
  trace = sw.toString();
}
```

Comment: I think you have to call the `toString()` method on the `StringWriter`, not on the `PrintWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array of `StackTraceElement` objects and append them to a `StringBuilder` like this:

```
Throwable t;
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("Throwable stack trace:");
for (StackTraceElement element : t.getStackTrace()) {
    result.append(element);
    result.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}

System.out.println(result.toString());   // print out the formatted stack trace
```